# how to rename id column in query MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have this column named "id". whenever I try to inner join like this "inner join tblBarangay as LB USING(id) I get an error Unknown column 'id' but when I try to rename it to 'brgy_id' it works (Is the word id in MYSQL is a function name?). I don't want to rename it because many of my PHP code queries will then needed to be changed. Now, how can I make it work without renaming the column name? Thanks.

**TableA:**

```
-------------------------------------------
id | brgy_name | description
1     New York   a city
```

**TableB:**

Comment: what does your 2nd table look like:

Comment: Now I know why, Unknown column 'id' error. It does not see the reference of the second table. it's been bugging me for weeks now. Thanks to you guys, you were really helpful.

Comment: no problem. Show up sooner next time!

Comment: hahaha.. I will... thanks again Drew.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `using` because first off I am too dense. Second, it is too implicit and I like to be explicit so I understand it and others too. So, if you just don't use `using` (because they don't have `id` in common as column names) you are all set by explicitly joining with `table1.id = table2.whatever`. And you don't have to alter your table at all.

The Takeaway: Don't use `using` for this situation. And don't confuse `USING` with some mandate that you need to alter your table forever, thus messing up all you other queries that work just peachie.

From the MySQL Manual Page entitled [JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the schema of second table, may be you dont have Id in second table "TableB"

Comment: Now I know why, Unknown column 'id' error. It does not see the reference of the second table. it's been bugging me for weeks now. Thanks to you guys, you were really helpful.